# SQL syntax on Node red sql node

Tags: sql, node.js, arduino, mariadb, node-red

The data has been passed from an Arduino to node-red by Serial Port and the data is formatted to be a json.In node-red it can get the data from the json. Then it would be passed into a function node to format into a SQL query so that it would be added to the database.

The SQL node is from node-red-node-mysql.

node red function

```
[
    {
        "id": "2d4f4e57.8fda6a",
        "type": "function",
        "z": "5b88858e4e0520c4",
        "name": "Format SQL query",
        "func": "// Set the table name and fields\nvar tableName = \"sensordata\";\nvar fields = [\"rpm\", \"water\", \"temp\", \"humidity\"];\n\n// Create the SQL query string\nvar values = [];\nfields.forEach(function(field) {\n    values.push(msg.payload[field]);\n});\nvar sqlQuery = \"INSERT INTO \" + tableName + \" (\" + fields.join(\",\") + \") VALUES (\" + values.join(\",\") +\")\";\n\n// Store the SQL query in the message payload\nmsg.topic = \"INSERT INTO sensordata\";\nmsg.payload = sqlQuery;\nreturn msg;",
        "outputs": 1,
        "noerr": 0,
        "initialize": "",
        "finalize": "",
        "libs": [],
        "x": 850,
        "y": 200,
        "wires": [
            [
                "712c1b95.f32b98",
                "f289552cbe4f28ea"
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

js in the function

```
// Set the table name and fields
var tableName = "sensordata";
var fields = ["rpm", "water", "temp", "humidity"];

// Create the SQL query string
var values = [];
fields.forEach(function(field) {
    values.push(msg.payload[field]);
});
var sqlQuery = "INSERT INTO " + tableName + " (" + fields.join(",") + ") VALUES (" + values.join(",") +")";

// Store the SQL query in the message payload
msg.topic = "INSERT INTO sensordata";
msg.payload = sqlQuery;
return msg;
```

part of arduino code

```
StaticJsonDocument<200> jsonDoc;
        jsonDoc["rpm"] = rpm;
        jsonDoc["water"] = Water;
        jsonDoc["temp"] = temp;
        jsonDoc["humidity"] = hum;
       
    
        // Serialize the JsonObject to a string
        char jsonString[200];
        serializeJson(jsonDoc, jsonString);
    
        // Print the JSON string to the serial monitor
        Serial.println(jsonString);
```

I have tried running the query by itself on phpmyadmin it works but when I run through the flow it would not go through.

The error

> Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

json data

```
{"rpm":223.2857,"water":0,"temp":27.9,"humidity":46}
```

The query

```
INSERT INTO sensordata (rpm, water, temp, humidity)
VALUES (223.2857, 0, 27.9, 46)
```

I want the data to be added into the database.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75798752/edit) the question to include the code from the function node so we don't need to import your whole flow to see what you are doing.

Comment: Also include the full package name of the mysql/mariadb node you have installed as there are several.

Comment: Post your JavaScript from your NodeRED function node would be easier for other to read your JavaScript than reading a chunk of serialised string like this `"func": "// Set the table name and fields\nvar tableName = \"sensordata\";\nvar fields = [\"rpm\", \"water\", \"temp\", \"humidity\"];\n\n.........msg.payload = sqlQuery;\nreturn msg;"`. Anyway, the JavaScript seems to be correct, but it does not actually the one that save the data into mysql, it only create a query string and send it to MQTT, so where and how do read the subscripted topic and save it to the mysql?

Comment: "Then it would be passed into a function node to format into a SQL query so that it would be added to the database". No, the function node you shown us does not add anything to database, it only create a query string and publish it to MQTT.

Comment: The output of the fuction is passed to a MySQL node
`
[
    {
        "id": "712c1b95.f32b98",
        "type": "mysql",
        "z": "5b88858e4e0520c4",
        "mydb": "f6a31e6f.2b31f8",
        "name": "MySQL",
        "x": 1020,
        "y": 200,
        "wires": [
            []
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "f6a31e6f.2b31f8",
        "type": "MySQLdatabase",
        "name": "",
        "host": "localhost",
        "port": "3306",
        "db": "intern",
        "tz": "",
        "charset": ""
    }
]
`

Answer (score 0):

change payload to topic

```
// Store the SQL query in the message payload
msg.topic = sqlQuery;
return msg;
```